# I tried to push my folder to Heroku and got the below msg

Tags: python, heroku

I am working on Udacity project and using windows, i also have anaconda installed, and within the udacity workspace i am using terminal to push the folder to heroku.

-----> Installing pip

-----> Installing SQLite3

```
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘/tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/.heroku/python/include/’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘/tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/.heroku/python/lib/’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
sed: can't read /tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/.heroku/python/sqlite3/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc: No such file or directory
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘/tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/.heroku/python/bin/’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
Sqlite3 successfully installed.
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting alabaster==0.7.12 (from -r /tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ad/00b090d23a222943eb0eda509720a404f531a439e803f6538f35136cae9e/alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting alembic==0.8.10 (from -r /tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/7d/7fcda63887d9726e0145e98802baf374ec8cf889325e469194cd7926c98e/alembic-0.8.10.tar.gz (976kB)
       Collecting altair==1.2.1 (from -r /tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/c4/0c3f6358e88a8d716ec5ac6ed20048da5d78444586e441e4e61aaf4ca6fb/altair-1.2.1.tar.gz (108kB)
       Collecting apache-airflow==1.10.2 (from -r /tmp/build_982dd157e013e9edfe38bb428d02a17a/requirements.txt (line 4))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/06/45fe64a358ae595ac562640ce96a320313ff098eeff88afb3ca8293cb6b9/apache-airflow-1.10.2.tar.gz (5.2MB)
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
             File "/tmp/pip-build-jwaifym1/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 429, in <module>
               do_setup()
             File "/tmp/pip-build-jwaifym1/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 287, in do_setup
               verify_gpl_dependency()
             File "/tmp/pip-build-jwaifym1/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 53, in verify_gpl_dependency
               raise RuntimeError("By default one of Airflow's dependencies installs a GPL "
           RuntimeError: By default one of Airflow's dependencies installs a GPL dependency (unidecode). To avoid this dependency set SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes in your environment when you install or upgrade Airflow. To force installing the GPL version set AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE

           ----------------------------------------
       Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jwaifym1/apache-airflow/

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on GitHub portal:

> For all those coming by, I have done a "deep" dive today to understand
>   this issue and found out that pip==9.0.1 (current latest) still comes
>   with a broken version of setuptools.
>
> This '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort' error is
>   unavoidable if you use python setup.py install on one of our packages
>   (they are all namespace packages).
>
> If you have a fresh environment and only use `pip install` to install
>   our packages, you will not have this issue.